# How can I edit playlists on an MTP device?

Tags: mtp, mp3-player, playlists

One of the few things I still use Windows for is managing files and playlists on my MP3 player, which uses MTP. MTP was quite buggy on Ubuntu for a while (timeouts, disconnects, etc), but with 16.04 it seems like it's finally stable. I can manage files on the device through the file manager. On Windows I can use the file manager to manage playlists as well. How can I manage playlists in Ubuntu?

The device in particular is a Creative Zen Mozaic. The playlists are in a separate folder with .zpl extensions, and they must be some kind of virtual file because they all have a file size of 0 bytes. If I copy the files to my computer they're empty.

I've tried copying .m3u files to the device but it doesn't seem to support them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few things and [gMTP](https://gmtp.sourceforge.io/) (`sudo apt install gmtp`) seems to do the trick. Not the prettiest UI but it works well for managing playlists over MTP. This is the solution I'll be sticking with unless I run across something better.

One other note: I've noticed for this particular device that MP3 tags don't show up for tracks when they're copied through the file manager. They only show up if they're copied using one of these MTP solutions, so that's another reason to use them.

For reference, here's what else I tried:

- [Gnomad 2](http://gnomad2.sourceforge.net/)
  `sudo apt install gnomad2`

  - This worked but the UX is pretty terrible. I had to use two separate parts of the application depending on whether I wanted to edit the playlist itself or add tracks to it. Some functionality failed silently, like shuffling playlists. And some functionality is completely lacking, like reordering tracks in a playlist. It hasn't been updated since 2011 so there's little hope there will be any improvements.
- mtp-tools
  `sudo apt install mtp-tools`

  - mtp-tools seems to have several utilities for managing playlists on an MTP device (mtp-newplaylist, mtp-playlists), and even though I generally prefer the command line this is one instance in which I'd prefer a nice GUI.
- [Rhythmbox](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox)
  `sudo apt install rhythmbox`

  - I tried Rhythmbox first and even though it displays tracks on the device, it doesn't seem to have any way to manage the playlists on the device.

Comment: Instead of posting what you have tried in the answer part, you should move this information to your question. [Edit your question here.](https://askubuntu.com/posts/957696/edit)

Comment: @Cynplytholowazy Good point, I didn't make it very clear that I found a solution. I've updated my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Put all your "What I have tried" in your question instead of your answer. It will make more sense to people.